What configuration can be changed to deal with the "current metadata capacity has exceeded the cluster quota" problem in Apache IoTDB?
Apache IoTDB reported an error: The current metadata capacity has exceeded the cluster quota. Please review your configuration on ConfigNode or delete some existing TIMESERIES to comply with the quota. I did not quite understand this error message, seems like there's an upper limit for region, database or time series. Can anyone explain more on what does this error mean? How to deal with it?

This error is because the number of time series you created has exceeded the limit of the measurements allowed in Apache IoTDB. If you are using open-source version, it is not recommended to adjust the parameter limits, so you may need to change your data structure. If you are using enterprise version, you can increase the number of measurements when applying for the license, or you can adjust the data structure yourself.
